# How can I change price '. "with "," in magento?

Tags: xml, magento

I have this page:

http://www.moment-of-style.com/onlajn-magazin/rubashki.html

Prices of products have the following form.

"17000.00"

I want to have the price as "17 000.00" (with space after the first two digits)

I tried to go to the next path:

lib/Zend/Local/Data/ru.xml

```
        <numbers>
        <symbols numberSystem="latn">
            <decimal>.</decimal>
            <group> ,</group>
            <list draft="contributed">;</list>
            <percentSign draft="contributed">%</percentSign>
            <plusSign draft="contributed">+</plusSign>
            <minusSign draft="contributed">-</minusSign>
            <exponential draft="contributed">E</exponential>
            <superscriptingExponent draft="contributed">×</superscriptingExponent>
            <perMille draft="contributed">‰</perMille>
            <infinity draft="contributed">∞</infinity>
            <nan>не число</nan>
        </symbols>
        <decimalFormats numberSystem="latn">
            <decimalFormatLength>
                <decimalFormat>
                    <pattern>#,##0,###</pattern>
                </decimalFormat>
            </decimalFormatLength>
            <decimalFormatLength type="long">
                <decimalFormat>
//some code

</numbers>
```

We made these changes but unfortunately still does not change.
What should be done to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you clean the whole cache after your change ?

Comment: What did you changed in this file actually ? You are in the right one as far as your local is defined to russia.